# StackOverflowError Collections::unmodifiableList

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I have found a strange random error with the StackOverflowError below. It is not deterministic, so I'm having a hard time trapping the issue... I have an Arraylist which is wrapped to an Collections::unmodifiableList(...), and then iteration is performed using for(Val val : myValues)

How is this even possible? The fields in the UnmodifiableList implementations in Collections are all final, so there can't be any circular dependencies (for instance A->B->A)). And no, reflection is not involved here either...

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)        
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)        
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
at com.server.ServerFunction$ServerFunctionResult.evaluateValues(ServerFunctionn.java:562)
at com.server.ServerFunction$ServerFunctionResult.access$300(ServerFunctionn.java:348)
at com.server.ServerFunction.perform(ServerFunction.java:1171)
```

Code which generates this (it has been re-written since I can't post the actual code here...):

```
public final static class ServerFunctionResult
{
    private final List<String> myValues;
    private final boolean myIsProcessed;

    public ServerFunctionResult(List<String> values, boolean isProcessed)
    {
        // Reduce object retention of empty list objects
        myValues = values.isEmpty() ? Collections.EMPTY_LIST : Collections.unmodifiableList(values);
        myIsProcessed = isProcessed;
    }

    public ServerFunctionResult evaluateValues()
    {
        if (!myIsProcessed)
        {
            for (String s : myValues) // <-- HERE IT THROWS
            {
                // Process values
            }

            return new ServerFunctionResult(myValues, true);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

This is Java 7u51. I've tried to wrap my head around this but right now I suspect JVM bug...

Is this issue familiar to someone else?

Comment: Can you put some code here?

Comment: Seeing your code would help.

Comment: How are you actually invoking this?

Comment: Seeing your REAL code would help even more.

Comment: Why are you creating a new object? Seems quite pointless. If you've processed this object's values, why not say so?

Comment: If the problem is not deterministic,  it could be a multithreading problem. I see no synchronisation in your code. Is your server multi threaded?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for the `UnmodifiableCollection` class from Java 7u40:

```
    static class UnmodifiableCollection<E> 
            implements Collection<E>, Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1820017752578914078L;
        final Collection<? extends E> c;
        UnmodifiableCollection(Collection<? extends E> c) {
            if (c==null)
                throw new NullPointerException();
            this.c = c;
        }

        ....

        public Iterator<E> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<E>() {
                private final Iterator<? extends E> i = c.iterator();
                public boolean  hasNext() {return i.hasNext();}
                public E  next() {return i.next();}
                public void  remove() {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                }
            };
        }
```

(You should have the actual source code in the JDK for Java 7u51.)

As you can see, when you call `iterator` on an unmodifiable collection, it creates an instance on an anonymous class.  The constructor for that class calls `c.iterator()` ... where `c` is the wrapped class.  However, the stacktrace implies that `c` is itself an unmodifiable collection.

I can think of a plausible explanation:

- If your application is (for some reason) wrapping unmodifiable collections in unmodifiable collections to N levels, then creating an iterator will result in N * 2 levels of stack frames.  For large enough N, that would lead to a stack overflow.

There are other possible explanations that involve either using reflection (or byte code engineering) to break type abstraction boundaries, or a hypothetical JVM (probably JIT compiler) bug.  Frankly, the JVM bug explanation is pretty implausible, but if I suspected that I would start by upgrading to the most recent Java 7 release.  (Actually, I'd probably do that anyway!  7u51 is missing 1 year of security patches and bug fixes on the Java 7 platform.)

Comment: Thank you for feedback. Problem is that the stack depth here is 41 000, so we don't wrap upon wraps that often. The wrapping occurs, though.